# Extraordinarily Simple Ruby Question: Where's My Class?

Tags: ruby

*[I'm just starting with Ruby, but "no question is ever too newbie," so I trudge onwards...]*

Every tutorial and book I see goes from Ruby with the interactive shell to Ruby on Rails. I'm not doing Rails (yet), but I don't want to use the interactive shell. I have a class file (first_class.rb) and a Main (main.rb). If I run the main.rb, I of course get the `uninitialized constant FirstClass`. **How do I tell ruby about the `first_class.rb`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to put them both in the same file.

However you can also use require, e.g.:

```
require 'first_class'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use autoload as follows:

```
autoload :FirstClass, 'first_class'
```

This code will automatically load first_class.rb as soon as FirstClass is used. Note, however, that the current implementations of autoload are **not** thread safe (see http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/174036).

Answer (score 2):

There's another point worth noting: you wouldn't typically use a `main` file in ruby. If you're writing a command line tool, standard practice would be to place the tool in a `bin` subdirectory. For normal one-off scripts the main idiom is:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  # main does here
  # `__FILE__` contains the name of the file the statement is contained in
  # `$0` contains the name of the script called by the interpreter
  # 
  # if the file was `required`, i.e. is being used as a library
  # the code isn't executed.
  # if the file is being passed as an argument to the interpreter, it is.
end
```

Comment: Hi ar2800276, thanks for that! In Java we have a static main method that can be put on any class. Is there some advantage to your "standard practice" way of doing this in Ruby?

Comment: >Is there some advantage to your "standard practice" way of doing this in Ruby?

The advantage is that the static class method doesn't exist in Ruby :)

Comment: Very cool. I don't know if I'll be doing any Ruby without Rails, anyway, but I do like to know the stuff just in case. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, the advantage of this idiom is so the `main` code doesn't run if the file is merely required.